# Cannot ping : "Network unreachable" after switching to NAT mode on VM

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I have a ubutnu server 14.0.4 running off a VM using bridge mode. When I do a ping google.com I get unable to "network is unreachable"

In my network/interfaces I have:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#The primay network inteface
auto eh0
adress "Ip adress of the ubtu server from ifconfig"
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast "same as ip address just with .255 at the end 
gateway default gateway on my home router
```

Everything was working fine until I switch Bridged to NAT then back to Bridge mode. If anyone can give me advice I would appreciate it. I do not care if I have to blow away some configs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if thats a copy paste of your interfaces file, but your interfaces file has some typos and is missing some config.

you have

```
auto eh0
 adress
```

need static line and fix typos of eth0 and address.
https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Configuring_the_interface_manually

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address
```

check the interface config that it has the IP etc assigned.

```
ifconfig eth0
```

Once making changes to the interface file you can ifdown/up to apply the new config.

```
ifdown eth0; ifup eth0
```

Comment: Maythux, your edit broke the context of my post. I was showing a before and after.